# How do I create my own Ubuntu version?

Tags: custom-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I don't like unity and I don't like xubuntu or kubuntu that much, so I want to know how I can create my own Ubuntu distro!

I want:

- a GUI
- only a terminal installed (no other unnecessary programs.)

I don't want

- Unity
- no browser, games, text editors or video players.

I basically want a distro that is easy to set up the way you want it. So as many ppa should be added as default.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Any changes you make to the core install is technically a change of distro. You could name it "Alvarbuntu." However, if you are asking how to make a distro, and are curious about the steps, then honestly I'm going to say distro creation isn't for you. Not to be condescending but there are various flavors of Ubuntu from cruchyroll to linux mint. You would be better off finding a distro that fits your needs and then creating an apt disk that loads all your programs.

Comment: I can't find a Ubuntu version that has a GUI and **JUST** a terminal installed. that is what I want, so I can change it to the way I want! :)

Comment: You should repost your question to the comment you just left since someone marked this as a duplicate question.  If you really want to make your own distro though it is possible and there are several wiki's and how to's out there.  I would not be the one to give you advice though as I have not tackled ubuntu 11.* at all yet.  I usually stay with LTS until it is no longer supported.

Comment: well my laptop crashed and froze on 10.04 but in 11.04 it's fine...

Comment: Use Ubuntu server then install what ever you want.